# UINavigationController + SplitView issue when setting the detailView from the masterView

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `SplitViewController` with two `UITableViewController` (let's call them A and B) managed by a `NavigationController` in the `MasterView`.
The `DetailView` is showing so called prepfiles (kind of images) which are set by clicking on the name of the prepfile in A. Then B shows up with more information to the prepfile.
When I hit the back-button from B to A the `DetailView` is cleared.

In the code below I am trying to set the current selected prepfile to the Master- and `DetailView` in a push segue from `UITableViewController` A to B. 
`self.detailViewController` is a pointer to the `DetailView`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    TestTVC *targetTVC = (TestTVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
    targetTVC.prepfile = self.prepfile;
    [self.detailViewController setPrepfile:self.prepfile];
    NSLog(@"detailController: %@", [self.detailViewController description]);
}
```

`self.detailViewController` is created in `viewDidLoad` as followed

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    self.detailViewController = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];    
}
```

This works fine until I hit the back-button from B to A and select the same prepfile again.
The `prepareForSegue` segment is called but in the `detailViewController setPrepfile` isn't called so the `DetailView` stays empty.
When I select another prepfile in A it works again.
Anybody any ideas why it won't work when selecting the same prepfile after going back in the `navigationController`?

Comment: If you're in `prepareForSegue:`, then `setPrepfile:` **has** to be called unless `self.detailViewController` is nil.  Can you use the debugger to try to step into `setPrepfile:` and see what happens?  (Also check for a nil controller.)

Comment: Sorry i forgot... This is why I call NSLog in prepareForSegue:  The detailController is never nil but it also never steps into setPrepfile: when I select the same prepfile after returning from B